# CSS change style of last element

Tags: css, wordpress, css-selectors

In wordpress template I have navigation meniu

```
<nav id="main-menu">
  <?php
  $home_url = home_url();
  $menu = wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'main', 'menu_id' => 'menu', 'echo' => false,                                           
  'menu' => 'LT')); 
  $menu = str_replace('#HOME_URL', $home_url, $menu);
  echo $menu;
  ?>
</nav>
```

I want that last of menu link will be red I try this

```
ul#main-menu li a:last-child{color: red;}
```

but it not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your structure is like that:

```
<ul id="main-menu">
    <li><a></a></li>
    <li><a></a></li>
</ul>
```

You have to use:

```
#main-menu li:last-child > a { color: red; }
```

As you're referring to the last `<li>`-element.